# Elasticsearch - different searchstring for different fields

Tags: elasticsearch

is it possible to query different fields with different searchstrings in one query?
For example:

```
{
  "query": [
    { "match": { "name": "Bob" }},
    { "match": { "title": "Awesome Title" }}]
}
```

where "name" and "title" are fields of documents.
I know there's a multi_match query, but there I query a list of fields all with the same string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query to search for documents that match both the conditions (`"name": "Bob"` and `"title": "Awesome Title"`). Replace the `<index_name>` with the name of the index.

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/<index_name>/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
          {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "Bob"
            }
          },
          {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": "Awesome Title"
            }
          }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
'
```

**Illustration:**

(a) Index 4 documents

```
# Doc 1 - Only "name" matches
$ curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/office/doc/o001" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "name" : "Bob",
    "title" : "Senior Staff",
    "description" : "Developing new products"
}
'

# Doc 2 - None of the criteria match
$ curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/office/doc/o002" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "name" : "Tom",
    "title" : "Marketing Manager",
    "description" : "Shows and events"
}
'

# Doc 3 - Only "title" matches
$ curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/office/doc/o003" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "name" : "Liz",
    "title" : "Awesome Title",
    "description" : "Recruiting talent"
}
'

# Doc 4 - Both "name" and "title" match - Expected in result
$ curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/office/doc/o004" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "name" : "Bob",
    "title" : "Awesome Title",
    "description" : "Finance Operations"
}
'
```

(b) Verify that the documents were indexed

```
$ curl 'localhost:9200/office/_search?q=*'

# Output
{"took":19,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":4,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"office","_type":"doc","_id":"o003","_score":1.0,"_source":
{
    "name" : "Liz",
    "title" : "Awesome Title",
    "description" : "Recruiting talent"
}
},{"_index":"office","_type":"doc","_id":"o001","_score":1.0,"_source":
{
    "name" : "Bob",
    "title" : "Senior Staff",
    "description" : "Developing new products"
}
},{"_index":"office","_type":"doc","_id":"o004","_score":1.0,"_source":
{
    "name" : "Bob",
    "title" : "Awesome Title",
    "description" : "Finance Operations"
}
},{"_index":"office","_type":"doc","_id":"o002","_score":1.0,"_source":
{
    "name" : "Tom",
    "title" : "Marketing Manager",
    "description" : "Shows and events"
}
```

(c) Run the query. Result is the one doc (with `id=o004`) that matches both criteria:

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/office/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
              {
              "match_phrase": {
                "name": "Bob"
                }
              },
              {
              "match_phrase": {
                "title": "Awesome Title"
                }
              }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 2
        }
      }
    }
    '
```

(d) Get the query result

```
{
  "took" : 27,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.4261419,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "office",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "o004",
        "_score" : 1.4261419,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Bob",
          "title" : "Awesome Title",
          "description" : "Finance Operations"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```